# How to estimate employee turnover?

Tags: interviewing, company-culture

**Motivation:** I think employee turnover is a great measure for employee satisfaction, especially if you believe in the [dead sea effect](https://en.everybodywiki.com/Dead_Sea_Effect) where a company's talent leaves more readily, causing accumulation of less capable members.

Objective: Knowing the employee turnover would allow applicants/ prospective employees to make a more informed decision. I guess the easiest way is to ask employees/ management, but asking a metric like this is unlikely to be consistent across companies, and very easy to lie about. I'm happy to accept strong alternatives to employee turnover as a measure of employee satisfaction, though Glassdoor reviews are particularly unhelpful for smaller companies which have been around for many years. (Only a small group of people write on Glassdoor).

This is different to median tenure (available on a Company's LinkedIn page), e.g. 1.2 years, because a company with fast growing employee count will skew their median tenure to 0.[image: LinkedIn screenshot of "Insights on Company" highlighting 3.3 years median tenure for Google.]

Comment: Count the number who leave, by year, month or week. But if it is not your data then getting data is the issue - why would any company want to give you that?

Comment: So that's why I asked the question, how do I get the estimate (depending on how you do it, you might/ not need the data)? A company would not give it to me (I didn't say *calculate*, i said *estimate*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame challenge: Turnover for the company is less immediately important to you than turnover in the team/department you're applying for, and that's something you can ask about before or during interviews. I've never received any pushback when I ask things like

- What's the average tenure of team members?
- How long has the hiring manager been there?
- Is this a new position or am I backfilling a role?
- [If previous answer is backfill and the role is senior] Is there a reason the role is being filled from outside instead of promoting a junior team member?

The answers to these should give you a feeling for the level of seniority of the team within the company, which in my experience is somewhat correlated with churn (though there will be exceptions).

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a valuable answer, those are excellent questions. I was going to delete my question, but wanted this to stay viewable to others. I think the culture of WorkPlace StackExchange is a bit tired if a new user asks a question and gets downvoted 3 times.

Comment: @BenButterworth: IME, this is a problem across the SE network. A new user asking a *hard* question is never dealt with very well.

Comment: "a feeling for the level of seniority of the team within the company, which in my experience is somewhat correlated with churn" - could you clarify this correlation, please? The more senior the team is, the higher the turnover rate?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper _inversely_ correlated, sorry :) and I mean seniority within the company, not as in the skill level label.